# How to change the default search field of a model in Odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to modify the default search engine of the existing model `mail.message`.

If you look for the word *Hello*, the search returns you all the messages whose `record_name` field contains *Hello*. But I need that it returns all the messages whose `body` contains *Hello*.

`mail.thread` model has a One2many field pointing to `mail.message`, and a lot of models inherit from `mail.thread`. For example, `sale.order`. Therefore, in the search view of `sale.order` you can do an advanced search and look for `Messages`. But as I wrote above, it's returning you the messages whose "*title*" (field `record_name`) contains the word you have wrote in the search textbox.

To change that, I did this:

```
@api.model
def _name_search(self, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100, name_get_uid=None):
    result = super(MailMessage, self)._name_search(
        name=name, args=args, operator=operator, limit=limit,
        name_get_uid=name_get_uid
    )
    mms = self.env['mail.message'].search([]).filtered(
        lambda r: name in r.body
    )
    l = [(r.id, r.record_name) for r in mms]
    return l
```

So far it's working OK, but I don't trust it's working OK in all cases, and I'm pretty sure that there must be a much better way to manage it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to override name_search when you need to change the default behavior in the many2one field because it's called from there. But if you need to change the search view default behavior it's the search method you need to override. I didn't understand what you need exactly sorry

Comment: @Cherif I put you a specific example: if you go to `sale.order` tree view (through the interface), and in the search view, you click on *Filters > Add Custom FIlter*, and you select *Messages > contains* and write *Hello* in the textbox, the filter returns you all the sale orders which have messages whose title contains *Hello*. I need the filter to return all the sale orders which have messages whose **body** contains the word *Hello*.

Comment: If you want this behaviour for one model just add a filter in search view.  But if you want this behavior for all models you are doing the right thing here.  Just update your code to take in consideration args arguement because it contains other domains some times.

Comment: Thank you @Cherif, I can't convert your comment in an answer, so copy my answer if you want and I'll set yours as the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Cherif comment is the right answer:

> If you want this behaviour for one model just add a filter in search
>   view. But if you want this behavior for all models you are doing the
>   right thing here. Just update your code to take in consideration args
>   argument because sometimes it contains other domains.

I wasn't taking into account the `args`, the `operator` and the `limit` parameters, so if I can't call the `super` of `_name_search` due to the situation, at least I must copy the part of the source code of `_name_search` which I'm not going to modify:

```
class MailMessage(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mail.message'

    @api.model
    def _name_search(self, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100,
                     name_get_uid=None):
        if args is None:
            args = []
        domain = args + [
            '|', ('model', operator, name), ('body', operator, name),
        ]
        return super(MailMessage, self).search(domain, limit=limit).name_get()
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try :

```
@api.model
def _name_search(self, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100, name_get_uid=None):
result = super(MailMessage, self)._name_search(
    name=name, args=args, operator=operator, limit=limit,
    name_get_uid=name_get_uid
)
mms = self.env['mail.message'].search([('body', 'like', name)])
return [(r.id, r.record_name) for r in mms]
```

Comment: What is the point from calling super if you don't do nothing with the result

Comment: @Cherif There is no point in doing that, it was my mistake. @Quentin improved my code, but my question is, is `_name_search` the method I have to overwrite to achieve my purpose?

Comment: You have to understand something doing it this way it's a bad thing because you are using a hard-coded domain. If you add a domain in your m2o field in the xml the domain will never change i think you need to take args in consideration. Take a look on how odoo uses args to extend the domain it's just a list concatenation.